# Pytest not collecting staticmethod

Tags: python, static-methods, pytest

I have a test class with some static methods along with normal methods. The problem is that `pytest` is not collecting static methods. I couldn't find anything in the documentation regarding this. How can I make it collect staticmethods too?

```
class TestFoo(object):
    @staticmethod
    def test_bar():
        assert 1 == 1

    def test_bar2(self):
        assert 1 == 1
```

In the above class, only `test_bar2` is collected and `test_bar()` isn't.

I am running `Python 2.7.13, pytest-3.1.2, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0`

Plugins are `xdist-1.17.1, leaks-0.2.2, cov-2.5.1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When collecting test functions, [pytest ensure each functions are callable](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/4e57a39067ddf1973ca2a6207423fdcd5916fa2e/_pytest/python.py#L273).

But a *staticmethod* is not callable, from https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html:

> Static method objects are not themselves callable, although the objects they wrap usually are.

see:

```
>>> class TestFoo(object):
...     @staticmethod
...     def test_bar():
...         assert 1 == 1
... 
>>> hasattr(TestFoo.__dict__['test_bar'], '__call__')
False
```

For this to work, pytest itself should be modified to accept static method, I don't know if that's what they want, you can open an issue on their issue tracker on github if you think you really need it.

Why do you think static methods are a solution? For which problem exactly?

Comment: Discussing if we should have static methods or not or if they solve any problem isn't the point. My codebase has them if the method doesn't use self. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Static methods in your codebase can be tested with normal methods of a test class (e.g. TestFoo). There is no need to decorate a test function of a staticmethod. It is the function in your codebase that is static, not the testfunction

Answer (score 0):

Pytest will collect and run test functions that are `@staticmethod`s since [v3.2.0 (2017-07-30)](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/changelog.html#pytest-3-2-0-2017-07-30).

```py
class TestFoo:
    @staticmethod
    def test_bar():
        assert 1 == 1
```