# Pytest collects a module twice with regex '*' argument

Tags: python, pytest

I have a module **TestEndToEndDemo.py** in a Python package **tests/**.

When I run `pytest tests/*`, the module is collected twice and each test within it run twice because of that, but when I run `pytest tests/TestEndToEndDemo.py`, the tests are executed only once.

There is one `@pytest.fixture` function used for dependency injection, and two `@staticmethod` test cases.

The tests/ module contains an empty ***init**.py* file.
Pytest --version 7.1.2
Python3 --version 3.10.4

Comment: If pytest is picking up anything at all then you've likely [changed the configuration in some unmentioned way](https://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html), In general, you should follow the convention of prefixing test files as `test_*.py`. Also, test methods should not be static. You can also use functional tests with pytest.. _Finally, the usual cli syntax does not use `*`. Try: `pytest tests` instead._ If this doesn't work,  please post an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, add info about your terminal/OS.

Comment: `pytest tests` did the trick. Thank you for the guidance @webelo. Can you explain why test methods should not be static?

Comment: See: [Pytest not collecting staticmethod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44703153/3422060)

Comment: I am not going to write an answer right now because - given the vague question statement -  my comments were just shots in the dark. If you wish to contribute to SO I would suggest that you revise your question to include relevant reproducible details. That way, someone else can benefit from the Q and answer.

Comment: @Nico remove the tests/__init__.py file and re-run the tests with, pytest tests/*

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

`pytest tests` instead of `pytest tests/*` removed the duplicates.